# How to calculate the product of the diagonal in Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I have given a sympy matrix, so a matrix consisting of real values and symbolic values and I want to calculate the product of diagonal entries of the matrix; An example:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *
from sympy.matrices import Matrix

A=sp.Matrix([[1,0,1],[2,3,1],[y,5,x]])
```

Now the desired result would be 3x; Of course I could do that with a for loop but is there some other, cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oscar Benjamin provided a slick solution. This will work as well:

```
np.product(np.diag(A))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diagonal` to get the diagonal elements and `prod` to multiply them:

```
In [46]: A.diagonal()
Out[46]: [1  3  x]

In [47]: prod(_)
Out[47]: 3⋅x
```

Comment: This gives me the following error: AttributeError: MutableDenseMatrix has no attribute diagonal. Is some function missing that I need to import first???

Comment: Perhaps you need to update to the latest version of SymPy.